# Can't launch PySpark in browser (windows 10)

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to launch PySpark notebook in my browser by typing in pyspark from the console, but I get the following error:

```
c:\Spark\bin>pyspark
python: can't open file 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the jupyter notebook is either not installed or not in your path.

I prefer to use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) for my python distribution and Jupyter comes standard and will install all necessary path information as well.

After that as long as you have set `PYSPARK_PYTHON_DRIVER=jupyter` and `PYSPARK_PYTHON_DRIVER_OPTS='notebook'` correctly you are good to go.

Comment: I have installed anaconda 3 and have set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON to ipython and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS to notbook. I this the correct setting?

Comment: Try changing `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` to `jupyter`

Comment: Also if you open up the pyspark file in your bin folder, not pyspark.cmd, in your editor you will find instructions for setting up the notebook.

Comment: Thx Grr2, but I don't understand the instructions in the pyspark file. Do I need to copy everything into here "(C:\Users\Eigenaar\Anaconda3) C:\Users\Eigenaar>"?

Comment: The gist of what I would take from the instructions are what values to set `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS` to. That being said I guess the first question I should have asked is: Does typing `jupyter notebook` in the command line work?

Answer (score 0):

You want to launch the jupyter notebook when you invoke the command `pyspark`. Therefore you need to add the following to the `bash_profile` or `zshrc_profile`.

```
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="pyspark-shell"

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook" pyspark
```